# Seam 2.x and Hibernate 3.5?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, seam, jpa-2.0

Does anyone know if Hibernate 3.5 is supported under Seam 2.x (specifically 2.2.x)?  I'm very interested in some of the JPA 2 features, particularly query building, but work within the Seam framework.  Is this version of the library supported?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://relation.to/Bloggers/TheTimelineForSeam3#comment15297), this should be possible if you also upgrade to Hibernate Validator 4 and use the legacy mode. Just in case, someone listed the Maven dependencies in [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1001094).

Comment: Thanks!  I'll be sure to give that a shot.